# iPhone text input field zoom- control zoom area

Tags: ios, iphone, zooming, input-field

So I'm working on a mobile form and I know that iPhone zooms in on input fields. The issue is that the iPhone is zooming in and cutting off the labels for each field (image attached). My client would like the form to zoom with the labels still showing (image attached).

I know how to stop zooming altogether, but that is not what we want to do.

Is there a way to add a margin/padding to the iPhone's zoom on the left to keep the labels visible? Or perhaps to set the zoom to focus on the left side?

[image: How the iPhone is zooming in]
[image: How we would like it to zoom]

Answer (score 0):

From what I've been told from our iOS guy, fighting with the iPhone's zooming features are not worth it. You can stop the phone from zooming at all, change the input font size so it won't zoom on a particular element, or live with the auto zoom.

In this case we ended up using a work-around and shortened the input fields so that when the phone zoomed it would show the entire field and the label at the same time.